Unable to execute arara (a TeX automation tool) from the Terminal
I can't execute arara (a command that is part of the TeXLive distribution) from the Terminal using bash shell.
I can execute tex which resides in the same directory.
Evans-iMac:~ evanaad$ cd ~
Evans-iMac:~ evanaad$ which tex
/Library/TeX/texbin/tex
Evans-iMac:~ evanaad$ echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools
Evans-iMac:~ evanaad$ ls /Library/TeX/texbin
...
amstex              mkofm
arara               mkpic
arlatex             mkt1font
...
fragmaster          teckit_compile
gbklatex            tex
gbkpdflatex         tex2aspc
...
Evans-iMac:~ evanaad$ which arara
Evans-iMac:~ evanaad$ arara --version
-bash: arara: command not found

My computer is iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) with some hardware upgrades
My OS is macOS Catalina v. 10.15.7
My TeXLive version is TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2024)
I have jdk installed java 19.0.2 2023-01-17 (this is, afaik, the latest version that can be installed on macOS Catalina)
I don’t know why this happens.
How can I rectify this?

Excellent. Let’s check the file type of that file. Also, are you sure executable is set on it? ls -l /Library/TeX/texbin/arara and file /Library/TeX/texbin/arara

@bmike ls -l /Library/TeX/texbin/arara outputs lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  39 Apr 13 21:44 /Library/TeX/texbin/arara -> ../../texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.sh. file /Library/TeX/texbin/arara outputs /Library/TeX/texbin/arara: broken symbolic link to ../../texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.sh.

There is no ../../texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.sh installed (or /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.sh which is where the symlink points to), this seems to be an error in the TeXLive distribution.

There is no ../../texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.sh installed (or /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/arara.sh which is where the symlink points to), this seems to be an error in the TeXLive distribution.
See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/721197/mactex-live-utility-always-asks-for-force-removal-of-arara-and-arara-universal-d for more details. A comment there recommends to run sudo tlmgr install arara to install it directly. Depending on how you installed TeXLive, sudo may not be required.
$ tlmgr install arara
tlmgr: package repository https://mirror.init7.net/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
[1/2, ??:??/??:??] install: arara.universal-darwin [1k]
[2/2, 00:00/00:00] install: arara [20140k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: command log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
$ arara --version
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

arara 7.1.5
Copyright (c) 2024, Island of TeX
arara is released under the New BSD license.
...

